# Get input field value in same page without refreshing page php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, form-submit

I am trying to send my input value to a code segment in the same page, but it doesn't work. Right now, I can't get the value in the code segment. This is my current code:

```
<?php
if ($section == 'codesegment') {
if ($_GET['hour']) {
echo $_GET['hour'];
//here i want call my method to update db with this value of hour...
}
if ($section == 'viewsegment') {
?>
<form id="my_form" action="#" method="Get">
<input name="hour" id="hour" type="text" />
<input id="submit_form" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<script>
var submit_button = $('#submit_form');

submit_button.click(function() {

var hour = $('#hour').val();
var data = '&hour=' + hour;


$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '',
    data: data,   
    success:function(html){
       update_div.html(html);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value without refresh your page you have to use javascript, you can try this:

```
$('#hour').onchange = function () {
    //type your code here
}
```

By the way, your php script is server side, according to this, you can't use the value without post/submit/refresh

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using

```
<input type="submit">
```

it sends the data to the **action** of the form, so whenever you are clicking the submit button before the onclick function gets called, it sends the data to the action and the page gets refreshed. So instead of using input element try something like this

```
<button id="submit_form"> Submit </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

two things,
 1. as yesh said you need to change the input submit to `button type=button` and add an `onClick` function on that button. Or you can give a the javascript function inside a function line `function sampleFn(){}` and call this function `onSubmit` of form.
 2. You need to give the javascript inside `document.ready` function since the script execute before the dom loading and the `var submit_button = $('#submit_form');` may not found. In that case there will be an error in the browser console.

Try to add errors in the post since it will help to debug easily.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do on the same page. you can write ajax call to another page with data where you can do the functions with the data.

Something like this

//form.php

```
<form id="hour-form">
   <input type="text" name="hour" id="hour">
   <input type="submit" name="hour-submit" >
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on('submit', '#hour-form', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           var data = $('#hour').val();
           $.ajax({
               url: "post.php",
               method: "POST",
               data: {'hour':data},
               success: function(data)
               {
                 //if you want to do some js functions
                 if(data == "success")
                 {
                    alert("Data Saved");
                 }
               }
           });
       });
   });
```

//post.php

```
if(isset($_POST['hour']))
{
   // do the php functions
   echo "success";
}
```